# Finding the general solution of a non-linear system of differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

In a mathematical physical situation, the following non-linear system of differential equations arises:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}= \frac{A}{z^3} \, , \\[12pt]
\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}= \frac{B \, \theta}{z^3} \, , \\[12pt]
\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}= \frac{C}{z^4} \, ,
$$
subject to the initial conditions:
$$
x(0) = 0 \, , \quad z(0)=h \, , \quad \theta(0)=\theta_0 \, .
$$
Here, $x$, $z$ and $\theta$ are real functions of $t$ (time), and $A$, $B$ and $C$ are known real numbers.
The goal is to determine the temporal evolution of the quantities $x$, $z$ and $\theta$.
Combining the last two equations, one immediately obtains
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{z} = \frac{B}{C} \, \theta \, \mathrm{d} \theta \, ,
$$ 
whose solution reads
$$
z = K \exp \left( \frac{B}{2C} \, \theta^2 \right) \, ,
$$
where $K$ is an integration constant to be determined from the initial conditions. 
I would appreciate it if someone here could let me know whether going beyond that is possible to yield an analytical solution of the problem.

Thank you,

har

---

Here $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ are small angles and taking the leading-order term in a Taylor series is a good approximation.

Comment: I think it is $\frac{B}{2C}\theta^2$ in the exponential. If you replace $z$ in the equation for $d\theta/d t$, it should give something like $\text{erfi}(\lambda \theta) = \mu t + \nu$. Similarly, you could express $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ as a function of $\theta$. It seems that $\theta$ is a better variable than $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the substitution $z = K \exp\left(\frac{B}{2C} \theta^2\right)$ (as corrected by Gribouillis), the equation for $\theta$ becomes

$$ \dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{C}{K^4} \exp\left(-\frac{2B \theta^2}{C}\right)$$

which has the implicit solution

$$ \text{erfi}\left( \frac{ \sqrt{2B}\; \theta}{\sqrt{C}}\right) = \frac{2 \sqrt{2BC} (k+t)}{\sqrt{\pi} K^4}$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary constant; from the initial conditions you want
$$ k = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} K^4}{2 \sqrt{2BC}}\; \text{erfi}\left( \frac{\sqrt{2B}\; \theta_0}{\sqrt{C}}\right)$$

$x$ can then be obtained as

$$ x(t) = x_0 + \frac{A}{K^3} \int_0^t \exp\left(- \frac{3 B \theta(s)^2}{2C}\right)\; ds $$